# How to display a page if the user is logged in

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I have a basic login where the code redirects the user to a page (google.com at the moment). How do I make it so that the page it redirects you to is only accessible if the user is logged in (they can't just type the URL and access the page). I understand that you have to use session start but have read around and cannot come up with a solution.

**login.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$servername = "localhost";
$serverUsername = "root";
$serverPassword = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $serverUsername, $serverPassword, "users");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";


$loginError = "";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $username = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]); 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Password FROM user_logons WHERE Username = ? LIMIT 1"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->bind_result($password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) { 
        header("Location: https://google.com/");
    }
    else {
        $loginError = "Invalid username or password!";
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Login Test</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Username: <input type="text" name="username">
  <br><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  <span class = "error"><?php echo $loginError; ?></span>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basically, before you perform the redirect you need to track in some way that the user is authenticated (along with any necessary information about the user, such as an identifier or username).  You can set values in `$_SESSION` to track this, for example.  Then your protected pages would simple check for this information when they load.  If it isn't present then the user isn't logged in and the protected pages would return an error or redirect to an unprotected page.

Comment: Simplest answer is set the `session` then on the other page start with `if(!empty($_SESSION['somevalue'])) { content here } else { your not authorized content here}`.

Comment: Oh, so i need to set a session variable and then check if the user has it on the other page?

Comment: But surely the other page will not recognise the session variable that has been set in the other document.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: @tadman would the solution below not work then? If not, why?

Comment: It's not a question of if it will work in this most trivial capacity, but if it will work *sustainably*. Will you ever be notified of a vulnerability in your code except to find out you've been hacked? Will you have someone else audit your code to look for vulnerabilities before-hand? Are you sure you're following all best practices? This is why a framework is better: It's code other people are testing and have a vested interest in ensuring is rock-solid and secure.

Comment: @tadman Ok. I will take a look into it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**login.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$servername = "localhost";
$serverUsername = "root";
$serverPassword = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $serverUsername, $serverPassword, "users");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";


$loginError = "";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $username = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]); 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Password FROM user_logons WHERE Username = ? LIMIT 1"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->bind_result($password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) { 
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = "true";
        header("Location: redirect.php");
    }
    else {
        $loginError = "Invalid username or password!";
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Login Test</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Username: <input type="text" name="username">
  <br><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  <span class = "error"><?php echo $loginError; ?></span>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**redirect.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome User<h1>

</body>
</html>

<?php
    }
    else { 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1 align = "center">Unfortunately, you will need to be logged in to view this section!<h1>
<p align = "center">To return to the login page <a href = "login.php">Click Here</a></p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    session_destroy();

?>
```